# Is a C# language version supported on other Frameworks besides the framework it was made for?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Recently I've been diving into C# language versioning. A well written source has of course been the documentation [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version). In there however were a couple of statements made that weren't all that clear to me. For example, in one part of the documentation it states:

> C# 8.0 is supported only on .NET Core 3.x and newer versions.

Is it stating that C# 8.0 is only supported on different versions of the framework .Net Core 3 (not on any other framework)?

Or is it stating that C# 8.0 is supported on other frameworks (such as on .Net 5 and .Net 6) that are released after framework .Net Core 3?

Comment: .NET 5 and .NET 6 are newer versions =)

Comment: @GuruStron .Net 5 and .Net 6 are the same framework?

Comment: [.NET 5.0 is the next major release of .NET Core following 3.1.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five). And [NET 6 is the next major release of .NET following .NET 5.](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/preview/6.0.0-rc.1.md?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#whats-new-in-net-6-rc-1)

Comment: @GuruStron so then .Net and .Net Core are the same framework but are not the same frameworks as .Net Standard and .Net Framework?

Comment: .NET Standard is not a framework but [a formal specification of .NET APIs that are available on multiple .NET implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) which is made less relevant with .NET 5. And  .NET Framework is a framework with different versions - 4.8 being the latest one.

Comment: @GuruStron If .Net Standard is not a framework then why is it listed in the table learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/… as a target framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stating that C# 8.0 is supported on other .NET Core versions (such as on .Net 5 and .Net 6) that are released after framework .Net Core 3.  However it is not supported on ".Net Framework", which is built-in to Windows.

Comment: Or, I'm assuming, Mono or Unity or UWP.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I noticed how you called .Net 5 and .Net 6 ".Net Core versions". But in the documentation (see table) they are not listed as ".Net Core" but simply as ".Net" in the Target Framework column. Is Net and .Net Core the same framework?

Comment: Microsoft is playing Microsoft branding games. _.NET 5_ is effectively the v.Next of _.NET Core 3.1_. They skipped over _4_ because the current versions of the Framework are 4.x. They dropped the _Core_ to emphasize the fact that the _Core_ versions are now the mainstream versions. Kinda like _Windows NT 5_ or _Windows 9_

Comment: @Flydog57 If "Core" was dropped,  then .Net 5 and .Net 6 "is" the .Net Core framework but an improved version of it?

Comment: Yes. .NET 5 (and 6) are follow-ons to .NET Core 3.1

Comment: @Flydog57 Is the framework .Net Core being renamed to .Net (i'm not referring to the .Net Framework in this case)? Or is .Net Core and .Net two totally different frameworks?

Comment: Starting with now, there is the ".NET Framework" (which will never get past 4.something - unless Microsoft changes its mind) and ".NET" which is the follow-on to ".NET Core"